# How do I create a different data set from existing data set with only certain variables and values that I need?

Tags: r, statistics

So, I have this data set where I have age of chicks (bird chicks) from day 2 to day 10 (2,4,6,8,10) and I have a mass data for each of them on 2,4,6,8 and 10 days. But, not all chicks survive till day 10. So how do I extract a datasheet in R, using the overall datasheet but get only those individuals that have values for each of those days for the mass. And if I also wanted to sort them by Mass and Tarsus. Data set of those that have values for both variables on those days.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order to ask a better question please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Include data and the code you have tried in the question, please.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is a placeholder for the name of your dataset.)